# Abbreviating name of corporate author in a citation call-out

Tags: citing, harvard-style

I am trying to cite a publication of the Environmental Protection Agency. I want the in-text citations to employ the abbreviation `EPA` but the bibliography to show `Environmental Protection Agency`. I am using the `dcu` bibliography style. How would I go about doing this?

I have tried

```
@misc{EPA1,
    author="{Environmental Protection Agency}",
    key="{EPA}",
    year={2019},
    title = {{Benefits of Green Chemistry}},
    url = {https://www.epa.gov/greenchemistry/benefits-green-chemistry},
    urldate = {October 28, 2019}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Your question is much too vague to be meaningfully answered, though.  What bibliography system are you using (BibTeX? biblatex?); what backend (bibtex? biber?); what TeX system are you using (LaTeX? plain TeX? conTeXt?).  We also need to see what you've tried.  Please consider adding a minimum working example, as well; it makes it much easier to help, and often solves your problem on its own.

Comment: I am a new user of LaTeX and have been using Overleaf. I updated the question, and hopeful it is more clear now what I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dcu` bibliography style is part of the `harvard` citation management package. As such, it is only partly compatible with the `hyperref` package. In contrast, the `natbib` citation management package is fully compatible with `hyperref`.

I therefore suggest that you (a) load the `har2nat` package, which translates the `harvard`-specific macro names into `natbib`-compatible ones and (b) use the `\defcitealias` and `\citetalias` macros of the `natbib` package to achieve your goal of using abbreviated, or aliased, citation call-outs.

Note that you will need to execute one `\defcitealias` instruction for each entry for which you want to employ an abbreviated, or aliased, author name in the citation call-outs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{EPA1,
    author="{Environmental Protection Agency}",
    key="{EPA}",
    year={2019},
    title = {{Benefits of Green Chemistry}},
    url = {https://www.epa.gov/greenchemistry/benefits-green-chemistry},
    urldate = {October 28, 2019}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{geometry}

\bibliographystyle{dcu}
\usepackage{har2nat} % don't load the 'harvard' package
\newcommand\shortcitet[1]{\citetalias{#1} \citeyear{#1}}
\defcitealias{EPA1}{EPA}

\usepackage{xurl}
\renewcommand\harvardurl{\textbf{URL:} \url}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
As proposed in \citet{EPA1}---hereafter: \shortcitet{EPA1}---the benefits of \dots
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```